# What are logos of these kind called? (Logos with a well defined square or rectangle)

Tags: typography, logo

Below are some logos with a well defined square or rectangle. What are logos of these kind called?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

They are called "Logotype with a square".

Seriously. There is no particular name for this apart from "Logotype" wich means a logo without a Symbol.